# How to allow only specific domains to receive Firefox HTTP referers?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, headers, http-referrer

Until then to hide the http-referrer, I put the Firefox variable `network.http.sendRefererHeader` (in `about:config`) to 0. But when I want to log in [edX](http://network.http.sendRefererHeader) this site ask me for my referrer.

That’s why I want to select domains I want to allow to see my referrer. I find the Firefox extension [Smart referrer](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/smart-referer/) but this one seems to be not work. When I activate it (with the variable `network.http.sendRefererHeader` in 2) all sites receive my http-referrer not only the ones on my white-list. And when I turn`network.http.sendRefererHeader` into 0, any domain could receive my referrer. Then you see that this extension not working.

Is there a solution to select the domains allowed to receive referers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [RefControl](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/refcontrol/) to control the HTTP Referer on a per-site basis.

Comment: This was what I am searching for. Now, I can log in to edX without sending my referer to all other sites. Thank you.